# Receber dados em JSON com cURL

Tags: php, json, libcurl, requisição

Estou enviando um cURL, para uma URL que vai devolver como resposta um JSON.
Pelo navegador, acompanhando com firebug, o retorno é em JSON, mas quando eu faço o mesmo procedimento pelo PHP, ele retorna uma página(que parece ter sido processada com o retorno do JSON), tanto é que se eu colocar `curlopt_followlocation, false` o retorno da página é em branco.

Como recebo o retorno da página em JSON? tentei algo como: `curlopt_httpheader, array("accept: application/json")` e sem sucesso.

tenho uma página X, onde eu recebo a resposta da pagina Y(onde eu faço o uso do curl), na pagina X o retorno da página Y vem em HTML ao invés de vim em JSON, e quando digo ao cURL para não sigar nenhum followlocation a página volta em branco.

Eu não gostaria de fazer via AJAX, e sim em PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Alexandre espero que ajude.

Tenho esse script funcionando sem problemas.

```
$url = "http://www.url.com.br";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Caso não ajude, coloque o código que está tentando para que possamos avaliar melhor.